# SplObjectStorage - detach behaviour

Tags: php, spl

I found [this comment on the PHP doc page](http://php.net/manual/de/class.splobjectstorage.php#116194) and was suprised about it.

His comment might not be the best, but I wonder why the output of the following script is "left in the storage: 2"? And why "Outputs:" does not show up "2".

I expect the storage to be empty after detaching all objects.

```
<?php
class A {
    public $i;
    public function __construct($i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
}

$container = new \SplObjectStorage();

$container->attach(new A(1));
$container->attach(new A(2));
$container->attach(new A(3));
$container->attach(new A(4));
$container->attach(new A(5));

foreach ($container as $item) {
    echo $item->i . "\n";
    $container->detach($item);
}
echo "== Left in storage ==\n";
foreach ($container as $item) {
    echo $item->i . "\n";
}

/* Outputs:
1
3
4
5
== Left in storage ==
2
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because by `detach`ing an object inside of a `foreach` loop, this prevents `SplObjectStorage::next` from working correctly. I was able to find this information in [this](http://php.net/manual/en/splobjectstorage.detach.php#97644) user contribited note in the PHP docs (so take that for what it's worth).

> If you want to detach objects during iterations, you should dereference objects, before you call next() and detach the reference after next()

There's also a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65629&edit=2) report available on this, and apparently the reason it doesn't work is because, while detaching, the method *rewinds* the container's internal array pointer which is what causes havoc while detaching inside of a loop.

In your case, following that note, you can change the loop removing objects from the storage container like this and it should work as expected:

```
$container->attach(new A(1));
$container->attach(new A(2));
$container->attach(new A(3));
$container->attach(new A(4));
$container->attach(new A(5));

$container->rewind();
while ($container->valid()) {
    $item = $container->current();
    echo $item->i . "\n";
    $container->next();
    $container->detach($item);
}
/* Outputs:
1
2
3
4
5
== Left in storage ==
*/
```